# Horizontal ScrollView in Xamarin.Forms with AspectFill-like Image Scaling

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm currently working on a Xamarin.Forms project and trying to create a horizontal scroll view with images. I want the images to scale similar to the PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom behavior in Windows Forms. I've tried a few approaches, including using a StackLayout within a ScrollView and setting the Aspect property to AspectFill on the Image elements.

However, regardless of the approach I take, the layout always requires horizontal scrolling. I want to ensure that the images fit within the available space without requiring scrolling.

Here's a simplified version of my XAML:

```
<ScrollView HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
    <StackLayout x:Name="menuStack1" Orientation="Horizontal" WidthRequest="500">
        <Image Source="your_image.png" Aspect="AspectFill" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" />
        <Image Source="your_image.png" Aspect="AspectFill" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" />
        <!-- Add more Image elements as needed -->
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I've experimented with different WidthRequest values and image sizes, but the issue persists. What am I missing? How can I achieve the desired behavior where the images dynamically scale within the available space without requiring horizontal scrolling?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code below:

```
    <StackLayout>
        <!-- First ScrollView with Button -->
        <StackLayout>
            <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Text="File" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" Clicked="Button_Clicked" TextTransform="None"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ImageButton Source="C:/Users/user/Desktop/icon.png" HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="60" Aspect="AspectFit" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <!-- Add more elements as needed -->
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Super! You can add more details to you post and check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.